# TensorFlow Object Detection API CSV file format

Tags: csv, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tfrecord

Im new to using TensorFlows object detection API but understand I need to convert a csv file to a TFRecord. I understand the format of the csv should be 8 columns, as follows:

filename, width, height, class, min, xmax, ymin, ymax

what im confused about is which corner of the image is assumed to be the origin?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The **top left corner** of the image is assumed to be the origin `(0,0)`, with the width (x coordinates) increasing as you move to the right and the height (y coordinates) increasing as you move downwards.

So basically, the bottom-right corner of the image would be indexed as `(width-1,height-1)`

The format that you described above is basically the `Pascal VOC` annotation format in which, for a particular bounding box

`xmin` denotes the x coordinate of the top left corner
`ymin` denotes the y coordinate of the top left corner
`xmax` denotes the x coordinate of the bottom right corner
`ymax` denotes the y coordinate of the bottom right corner